# What happens to the angels post tikkun olam?

Tags: messiah, malach-angel, olam-haba-world-to-come, repentance-teshuvah

What happens to the spiritual entities such as the angels when the tikkun olam is complete and Moshiach has arrived? Will they also attain a place in Olam Haba?

Comment: Who said the arrival of Mashiach will mean the world is fully fixed? We'll still need to do Mitzvot.

Answer (score 1):

The [Yerushalmi in Shabbos](http://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Shabbat.39b?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all) says that in the future the Jews will be closer to Hashem than the angels, and that the angels will be asking us what Hashem is doing.